# Node NPM unable to require package by name only path

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I created a new Node Package to start sharing a project that I'm working on, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting my require statement to work.

Project: https://github.com/kcjonson/indigo

The issue that I'm having is that requiring my module this way:

```
var indigo = require('indigo');
```

Does not work, but requiring it by more explicit path like:

```
var indigo = require('indigo/lib/indigo');
```

works just fine.

**I assume this is an issue with my package.json file** which is as follows:

```
{ 
"author": {
    "name": "Kevin Jonson",
    "email": "kcjonson@gmail.com",
    "url": "http://kevinjonson.com"
},
"name": "indigo",
"description": "Node.js Facade for Perceptive Home Automations Indigo home automation servers python REST API",
"version": "0.0.7",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url":  "git://github.com/kcjonson/indigo.git" },
"directories": {
    "lib": "./lib"
},
"main:": "lib/indigo.js",
"license": "MIT",
"private": false
}
```

I've successfully added it to NPM and running `npm install` on the project that is using it does download the correct latest version and places it in the node_modules directory as expected.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is going to work but still worth a try I guess.

Try removing 'directories'

Comment: Still not working, commit here:
https://github.com/kcjonson/indigo/commit/ea982bc038bd8d03db9abb1e592e6518dd15bf10